# Implementing handlers in an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I have a handler in an Eclipse plugin (developed on Indigo) that I want to run every time a Java file in a text editor is saved (or opened, ideally). As far as I can gather, there are two ways of achieving this:

1. Programattically via the `CommandService` API.
2. Using the configuration in `plugin.xml`

I've tried both of these. Method 1 like this:

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI
              .getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
        commandService.addExecutionListener(new MyListener());
        plugin = this;
    }
    ...
}

public class MyListener implements IExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void postExecuteSuccess(final String commandId, final Object returnValue) {
        System.out.println("PostEventSuccess:" + commandId);
    }

    @Override
    public void preExecute(final String commandId, final ExecutionEvent event) {}

    @Override
    public void notHandled(String commandId, NotHandledException exception) {}

    @Override
    public void postExecuteFailure(String commandId, ExecutionException exception) {}
}
```

and method 2. like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler 
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
        class="mypackage.MyHandler">
        <activeWhen>
            <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow">
                <instanceof value="org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow"/>
            </with>
        </activeWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

Method 1. doesn't run my listener at all. Method 2. works, in that the handler is executed, but my handler seems to replace the default handler. When the user tries to save the file my handler runs but the file doesn't get saved. The handler itself seems to be fine (I've tested it by creating a menu item that runs it).

Is Method 1. deprecated now or have I implemented the service incorrectly? How do I get method 2. to save a file? Can the default handler be run from my handler?

Comment: These two do not differ just in that one is programmatic and the other declarative. I think defining the command handler is wrong as this *handles* the command execution instead of just being notified that the command was executed. Maybe I dig up something on the first method, which seems ok from the looks of it.

Comment: Are you positive that your plugin was activated, in other words, did that code in `start` actually run?

Comment: Good question. When I put some `println` statements in the Activator and Listener it seems as if that code isn't being run. However, the configuration is pointing to the right `Activator` class. Very odd.

Comment: Make the plugin start eagerly. That's configured in MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: I'll rework this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two do not differ just in that one is programmatic and the other declarative. I think defining the command handler is wrong as this handles the command execution instead of just being notified that the command was executed. Your first approach seems fine, but your code doesn't get executed until the plugin has been activated, which happens lazily, when the first class from your bundle is loaded. There is a workaround in Eclipse: contribute to the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point. Make e.g. your `Activator` class implement `IStartup`, you can use an empty implementation -- the only point is to get the framework to load *any* class from your bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed that from the manifest but the `Activator` still doesn't seem to load the listener, or even run the `start()` method.

Comment: Edited the answer. You don't need to remove that ActivationPolicy line for this new approach to work.

Comment: tried this but must have done something wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165610/eclipse-plugin-save-command-sucess