# Eclipse plugin save command sucess

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to implement a plugin to eclipse that logs something to a server everytime the use saves a file.
The file can be of any type (html, js, css, java, py).
I have the following:

```
package tstsave;
import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.commands.ICommandService;
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin implements IStartup {
    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "tstsave"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private static Activator plugin;

    public Activator() {
        Log.log("Activator()");
    }

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
        commandService.addExecutionListener(new SaveListener());
        plugin = this;
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

    public static Activator getDefault() {
        return plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public void earlyStartup() {
        Log.log("earlyStartup()");
    }

}
```

My listener

```
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.IExecutionListener;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException;

public class SaveListener implements IExecutionListener  {

    @Override
    public void notHandled(String arg0, NotHandledException arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postExecuteFailure(String arg0, ExecutionException arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postExecuteSuccess(String arg0, Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("test");
        Log.log("postExecuteSuccess");
    }

    @Override
    public void preExecute(String arg0, ExecutionEvent arg1) {

    }

}
```

the simple logger

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Log {
    public static void log(String message){
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\filename.txt"), "utf-8"));
            writer.write(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report
        } finally {
           try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {/*ignore*/}
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin doesn't seem to work, it is never called. Any tips?

Comment: Have you checked that the Activator start method is running?

Comment: Nothing in the activator is being called, don't know why. I even removed the Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy from the manifest

Comment: You have used `IStartup` - have you actually used the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

I had to create another class and also add the org.eclipse.ui.startup extension point.

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;

public class StartupClass implements IStartup {

@Override
public void earlyStartup() 
{

}
}
```

and the plugin.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
         <startup class="myplugin.StartupClass" />
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Thanks @greg-449